# How to store file content permanently?

Tags: c++, file

I want store approximate pi number from "approximate" file and use it afterwards, somehow it getting deleted and i can't print it after close method. Here's how i tried to.

```
string pi;
ifstream piFile;
piFile.open("pi_approximate");

while(piFile){
getline(piFile,pi);

}

piFile.close();
cout << pi << endl;
```

Comment: Without knowing that file content difficult to say, looks like it has empty line at the end and that what you get in `pi` variable after the loop - last line.

Comment: File includes 100 digit approximate pi number without trims, also file type is text. @Slava

Comment: This is the C++ equivalent to [why is while(!feof) always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: yes, should I delete the post ?

Answer (score 0):

This will keep reading from the file until it gets a failed read.  If the last character read from the file was a newline then that failed read will be immedaitely after clearing the string `pi`.  So after the loop exits, `pi` will be empty.